# How do I fix my SD card reader on my computer that always says the device is locked for read only?

Tags: sd-card, dell-xps, micro-sd-card, card-reader

When I insert a micro SD card into a SD adapter to read it in the SD card reader on my Dell desktop it says the drive is read-only whenever I try to copy files to it. The LOCK switch on the SD adapter is not in the LOCK position. I tried 3 different SD adapters. I am able to insert the micro SD card into the SD adapter into an USB card reader and write to the micro SD that way, but it is very slow (only 6MB/s) and inconvenient to use an extra piece. How can I fix the SD card reader to be able to write to the micro SD card?

Comment: Not all SD adapters are of equal quality, here is a similar issue, turns out it was a bad adapter....https://superuser.com/questions/406739/disable-write-protection-on-micro-sd?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I flicked the LOCK tab of the SD adapter about 30 times up and down and then it started to work.